# Целесообразность фабричного метода

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть некоторая иерархия классов, где каждый последующий класс наследуется от предыдущего.

Мне хотелось бы, что бы каждый класс имел свой статический метод `Parse`, который бы принимал строку и возвращал построенный объект.

Как я понимаю, переопределить статический метод в классах потомках нельзя, а можно только через перекрытие с и спользованием `new`...

Так вот, вот вопрос в том, правильно ли это делать через статический метод или есть какой-то другой вариант?

Comment: Какой `new`, какое _переопределение_? Просто пишите в каждом классе свой метод `Parse` и всё. Тем более, что возвращать они должны разные типы.

Comment: Как вы собираетесь переопределить статический метод и даже более интересный вопрос - как вы будете его вызывать без переопределения. Да и зачем такое может понадобиться?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что это фабричный метод?))

Comment: @srvr4vr Ну это правда фабричный метод, он же конструирует объект класса. Или может я не прав?

Comment: Вас сбивает с толку название) Там несколько сложнее если почитать про паттерн)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну перегрузки по возвращаемому типу, вроде, нет. А new нужно писать при объявлении метода, что бы убрать предупреждение компилятора о перекрытии такого же метода из родительского класса.

Comment: Верно, тип возвращаемого значения метода не является частью его сигнатуры, так что без new не обойтись. @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: *правильно ли это делать через статический метод* — правильно, делайте

Comment: @tym32167, автор хочет писать `Employee.Parse(x)`, `Engineer.Parse(x)`, `ChiefEngineer.Parse(x)` и т. д. Т. е. это не переопределение по сути. Просто у каждого конкретного класса должен быть статический метод с определенным названием, без new это не сделать, ну и иерархию фабрик лишнюю сочинять в этом случае тоже смысла нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробую ответить, отталкиваясь от термина [Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), который вы использовали.

Предположим, что у вас есть некая сложная иерархия:

```
interface IType;
class Type : IType;
class SecondType : Type;
class ThirdType : IType;
```

Вы ходите иметь возможность делегировать инстанцирование объекта, пользуясь всеми преимуществами полиморфизма, чтобы создать что-то вроде такого класса:

```
class TypeProcessor<T> where T : IType
{
  public void Process(string input)
  {
    var someObject = T.Parse(input);
    Console.WriteLine(this.ProcessInternal(someObject));
  }

  protected string virtual ProcessInternal(T value)
  {
    return value.ToString();
  }
}
```

Такой код не будет работать, потому что `static` методы не наследуются, да и для такого не предназначены.

Зато мы можем сделать прямо так, как предполагалось в этом шаблоне проектирования изначально, а именно - создать абстрактную фабрику (или интерфейс фабрики) и фабрики-наследников для конкретных типов:

```
interface ITypeFactory<T> where T : IType
{
  T Parse(string input);
}

class TypeFactory : ITypeFactory<Type> where T : IType
{
  public virtual Type Parse(string input) { ... }
}

class SecondTypeFactory : TypeFactory
{
  public override Type Parse(string input) { ... }
}

class ThirdTypeFactory : ITypeFactory<ThirdType>
{
  public ThirdType Parse(string input) { ... }
}
```

Соответственно в нашем классе `TypeProcessor` произойдут изменения:

```
class TypeProcessor<T> where T : IType
{
  private readonly ITypeFactory<T> factory;

  TypeProcessor(ITypeFactory<T> factory)
  {
    this.factory = factory;
  }

  public void Process(string input)
  {
    var someObject = this.factory.Parse(input);
    Console.WriteLine(this.ProcessInternal(someObject));
  }

  protected string virtual ProcessInternal(T value)
  {
    return value.ToString();
  }
}
```

Собственно, об этом и говорит паттерн Фабричный метод (можно посмотреть картинку на wiki). Есть `Creator` для общего типа и `ConcreteCreator`, который создает объекты конкретного типа.

В дополнение приведу [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/206082/), где автор рассуждает на тему использования статики в C#.